# Draw 20 arcs to create a circle

Tags: html, geometry, kineticjs

I'm stuck with a problem.
I'm trying to create a circle from 20 arcs, using the Kineticjs library.

The problem :
the arcs won't show up on my page....

I'm new with this library, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Could somebody please read the code on the following page and help me out ?

http://jsfiddle.net/cMHv5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting the arc variable.

To debug this, you should have tried adding a few console.log messages to see exactly what parameters you were calling Kineticjs functions with.

The first and the last lines of this snippet from your code are the problem:

```
var arc = Math.PI / (numbers.length/2);
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    (function() {
        var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
        var odd = i%2;
        var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({...});
```

[*Edited to add another problem:*]

I recommend simplifying your example and getting a simple arc to draw correctly before making it more complex.  Right now you're calling `context.arc()` to create a path, but you aren't actually drawing it--try calling `context.stroke()` and/or `context.fill()`.

After that, I think you need to look at the angles you're passing to `context.arc`--I'm not sure what you want the result to look like, but I don't think you're computing the angles correctly.

Comment: Thnx John,
I even did not noticed that.
I changed my code, but that doesn't help.
The arc's are still not displayed on the screen...

The updated version:
http://jsfiddle.net/cMHv5/10/

Any ideas left ??

Comment: Here's a version of that fiddle that has been modified a minimum amount to at least draw something: http://jsfiddle.net/johnwiseman/cMHv5/17/